# Some users getting a 404 when previewing draft posts/pages

Tags: 404-error, user-roles, multisite, draft, previews

I have a WP network and have found that users with roles other than "super user" (admins, editors, authors, etc.) are getting a 404 when trying to preview draft posts/pages/custom post types.

Any idea why this would be? I have the following:

- Version 3.1.4
- Subdomain network install
- Domain mapping plugin (if this matters)

Thanks.

Comment: Bump. Is there anyone else that has come across this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Found [this forum article](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/post-preview-does-not-work). It was an issue with the domain mapping and cookies. I ended up making sure the following options were both checked in the Domain Mapping options:

- Remote Login
- Redirect administration pages to site's original domain (remote login disabled if this redirect is disabled)

Answer (score 1):

Solved mine following this http://wordpress.org/support/topic/404-error-while-previewing-a-draft

Comment: Lone link is [considered a poor answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq#deletion) since it is meaningless by itself and target resource is not guaranteed to be alive in the future. Please try to include at least summary of information you are linking to.